# DOCX to PDF: SaveAs2 vs ExportAsFixedFormat vs PrintOut

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-word, office-interop

I have the tiny goal to convert a huge load of docx files to pdfs using C# and .NET without opening Word (visibly) and without using any third party library (less components to manage and less money to spend). At the moment, I am trying to correctly convert a single document, which has to be as efficient as possible in order to quickly convert the huge load mentioned before (several thousand docx files, each between 100 and 300 kb).

I am

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

and I am creating an instance of the Word application as follows
([explicitly without `ScreenUpdating = false` due to this option causing custom borders not to be converted into the result](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9e43a36c-00de-4edf-8022-e93dcaeca69b/text-border-missing-when-exporting-from-word-to-pdf-via-com-interop?forum=worddev)):

```
private static Word.Application word = new Word.Application()
{
    Visible = false
};
```

as well as opening the document to be converted the following way

```
Word.Document docxFile = word.Documents.Open(sourcePath, Visible: false);
```

There are 3 ways I have successfully used to convert a docx file of 100 kb to a pdf:

## `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.SaveAs2`

```
docxFile.SaveAs2(FileName: outputPath,
                FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

```
Duration     |  pdf size
————————————————————————
757,5307 ms  |  277 kb
```

---

## `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.ExportAsFixedFormat`

```
docxFile.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName: outputPath,
                            ExportFormat: Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                            OptimizeFor: Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen);
```

```
Duration      |  pdf size
————————————————————————
783,51333 ms  |  285 kb
```

---

## `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.PrintOut`

```
docxFile.Activate();
docxFile.PrintOut(
    OutputFileName: outputPath,
    PrintToFile: true
);
```

```
Duration     |  pdf size
————————————————————————
998,5403 ms  |  290 kb
```

This last option has two additional downsides:

- it opens a small dialog or popup that shows the printing progress, I guess that causes the slightly extended run time
- the document has to be activated before by `docxFile.Activate()`, otherwise a `COMException` is thrown

---

**Time measurement / estimation:**
I simply took a `DateTime.Now` before starting the conversion on an already opened document and took another `DateTime.Now` after having closed that document. Then I subtracted the first from the second one:

```
DateTime conversionBegin = DateTime.Now;
// conversion followed by closing the document
...
DateTime conversionEnd = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan conversionTime = conversionEnd.Subtract(conversionBegin);
Console.WriteLine("Conversion time: " + conversionTime.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
```

I am aware of this not being a very reliable time measurement, but I don't really need one. I just wanted to see if there are significant differences.

That all leads to the (one) question...

## Why does the content of each of the resulting pdfs look exactly the same but the conversion time is different and the resulting files have different sizes?

**Maybe I remove the following text to avoid close votes, but for now:

This is just a request for additional information, the question to be answered is the one above**:
I would love to additionally read opinions, hints, recommendations or advices targeting the questions

**What is the preferred way to convert a docx to a pdf when it comes to several thousand conversions in one run?**
and
**What parameters or parameter values of the methods might improve the conversion time?**

Comment: Do you happen to have SharePoint on-premises? If yes, use Word Automation Services. As to the question about how/why the results: That would require intimate knowledge of the Microsoft code and the Adobe "engines" that are used.

Comment: @CindyMeister Unfortunately, I don't really know... Have to ask an administrator. Will take some minutes...

Comment: @CindyMeister OK, there is no SharePoint on-premise available. I will have to choose one of the options myself then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: FWIW In your place I'd run tests on a large sampling of documents with varying content to see whether the results (the appearance of the pdfs) differ or are the same in all cases. If they differ, choose the method that produces the best result. Beyond that, my inclination would be to go with SaveAs2 as that seems to be more reliable across systems (Windows versions, Mac), based on questions I've seen over the years.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the advice. For now, I have to stick to `PrintOut` because of another issue: I have to print only pages that actually have content and aren't blank due to various section breaks that make the document continue on the next odd or even page. I wasn't able to adjust the document accordingly before `SaveAs2` or `ExportAsFixedFormat` because I cannot tell them to export/save pages `"1, 3, 4, 5, 6"`, for example. The result is not really good because the printer settings seem to add additional spaces around the result.