# How can I replace a plain URL string in a Paragraph.Text by a Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, url, hyperlink, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Microsoft Word Document with several `Paragraph`s and I have to replace a plain URL in one of the paragraphs by a `Hyperlink` that can actually be clicked.

The entire link is known before, I just have to find the paragraph containing it and thenreplace that text by a real link (HTML doesn't work).

```
// this is how I determine the positions in the text of the paragraph
var urlStartIndex = paragraphRange.Text.IndexOf(linkUrl);
var urlEndIndex = urlStartIndex + linkUrl.Length;
```

but I am not able to replace just the part of the `Paragraph.Text` with a link.

The example text in the paragraph is like

```
Click the following link: https://www.somewhereinthe.net/something/somethingmore
```

where just the part starting with `https` should be entirely replaced by a real link to make it

```
Click the following link: somewhere
```

At first, I tried to directly insert it instead of the url, but simply removing the url and pasting the link instead can obviously not easily be done.

The following try replaced the entire paragraph by a link that is clickable but not highlighted (blue and underlined font), but has its `TextToDisplay` as `Address`, too, and thus, leads to nowhere in the web:

```
private static void ReplacePaypalLinkIn(Word.Paragraph paragraph, Word.Document docx, string linkUrl)
{
    var paragraphRange = paragraph.Range;
    // find the start index of the url
    var urlStartIndex = paragraphRange.Text.IndexOf(linkUrl);
    // calculate the last index of the url
    var urlEndIndex = urlStartIndex + linkUrl.Length;
    // and add it to the hyperlinks of the document at this very paragraph (Anchor)
    var link = docx.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor: paragraphRange, Address: linkUrl, TextToDisplay: "somewhere");
}
```

How can I replace that URL in a way that actually results in a `Paragraph` that includes the text before the URL and, instead of the URL, a clickable and well formatted link substituted by the given `TextToDisplay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word manages hyperlinks through HYPERLINK ***fields***. Fields are what Word uses to work with dynamic content. Some examples, besides hyperlinks, are page numbers, dates, cross-references - anything that can change or trigger an action.

So what needs to happen here is 1) locate the URL and 2) replace it with a hyperlink.

Usually, it's expedient to use Word's `Find` feature to locate a specific string in the text. (The technique illustrated by the code in the question relies on the *index location* of the string in the document. This approach is, unfortunately, not at all reliable as Word document's tend to harbour "hidden characters": control characters that aren't visible, but change the index location values of document content.)

The following code snippet demonstrates how to use `Find` to locate the URL string in the document and insert a Hyperlink (field) in its place, using the method `Hyperlinks.Add`:

```
string targetUrl = @"https://www.somewhereinthe.net/something/somethingmore";
string displayText = "somewhere";
Word.Range rngUrl = doc.Content;

Word.Find fd = rngUrl.Find;
fd.Text = targetUrl;
bool success = fd.Execute();
if (success)
{
    doc.Hyperlinks.Add(rngUrl, targetUrl, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, displayText, Type.Missing);
}
```

What various properties are available for `Find` can be found in the Word language reference. It's a good idea to understand what all can be involved when `Execute` runs. What's shown here is reduced to what's needed to demonstrate the basic principle.

What's important to know, immediately, is that the `Range` the search is running on will switch to the "found" term. So `rngUrl` begins by encompassing the body of the document, but on locating the URL, it reduces to the URL. Thus, the hyperlink will replace the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this snippet and the explanation. This works perfectly... Now I know I have to find out more about `Find`.

Comment: Can I use `Find` in order to remove empty pages caused by any section break (odd or even)? My final goal is to replace a URL by a link (this question, thanks again for the answer), remove empty pages (future question, maybe) and convert it to a pdf ([older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991409/docx-to-pdf-saveas2-vs-exportasfixedformat-vs-printout?noredirect=1#comment107972382_60991409)).

Comment: @deHaar Please ask this as a new question with complete information to reproduce the kind of situation in question. My inclincation is to say NO, based on what I understand from the comment, but the information provided may not be complete. And anyway, questions and answers do not belong in comments...

Comment: You are right, they don't belong in comments... However, I managed it as it seems now (used `Find` to replace section breaks `"^b"` by page breaks `"^m"`). If that turns out to be unreliable, I will ask a new question for sure.

Comment: @deHaar Well, yes, to delete the section breaks. But you ask about deleting the pages generated by the breaks - that's something totally different. Which is why I did not try to respond with any kind of answer - too little concrete info.

Comment: Yes, I provided too few information by talking about *empty pages* instead of *empty pages caused by section breaks to next odd page*. Will keep in mind for possible future questions.